# How to update a test execution when importing Junit Multipart using Xray?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I was looking at the documentation of the Xray plugin for Jenkins: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-JUnitXMLresultsMultipart

And what I found, is a bit confusing, after a few attempts.
If I'm NOT trying to import executions using the multipart, I can update a test execution by specifying a Test Execution Key.

When I do try the multipart, I have this JSON

```
 "fields": {
   "project": {
     "key": "${ProjectKey}"
   },
   "summary": "Temp Test execution",
   "issuetype": {
     "name": "Test Execution"
   },
   "labels": [],
   "fixVersions": [
     {
       "name": "testrelease"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

This always creates a new Test Execution within JIRA.
In their examples I see no way to send the test execution key for it to be updated.
Which is strange, because by importing without multipart, I can set it.

Anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, if you use the "multipart" kind of endpoints, a new Test Execution will always be created. To update existing Test Execution issues you need to use the standard endpoints (e.g., [JUnit](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-JUnitXMLresults)); however, these don't allow you to customize fields on the Test Execution.
There's an [improvement in the backlog](https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAY-6221) in order to enhance the existing behaviour; please vote on it and watch it, so the Xray team can become aware of your interest on this.